# Netbeans 7.3.1 add server Glassfish 4.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, netbeans-7, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

I updated Glassfish server from 4.0 to 4.1 but now if i add it in Netbeans 7.3  I have "Not a valid GlassFish Server installation" .Netbeans doesn't find Glassfish. How can i solve without install Glassfish 8.0.1?

Comment: I solved it .I installed Netbeans 8.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Reason for Not a valid Glassfish server Installation could be you may not give correct Server(Glassfish/Tomcat) installation folder. Adding server to your project is as follows

Go to Services tab , Select Servers then right click on it. Select Add Server. Select your server(Glassfish) and name it then click next.

In Server Location give correct installation location (in my pc, `c:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1`) the click next. Give Domain name as you like it. Do not use default port. Leave Target name, username, password then click Finish. It will show Domain creation successful.

For Ref: [Create Glassfish server](http://netbeans.dzone.com/nb-class-glassfish-resources)